# This page isn’t working www.janmukti.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: sql-server, laravel, phpmyadmin

It's the first time I am putting my laravel project into the server. I made a laravel directory inside home directory and kept all directories of my project except the Public into it. I then kept my public directory inside the laravel_html directory using filezilla. Permissions are set to 777.I also changed the contents of .env file and index.php file accordingly.. still I am not able to get the page www.janmukti.com .. any idea how to fix

Answer (score 2):

You need to set permission to `/storage/cache` and `/bootstrap` directories.
You can use this thread to see how to set permissions to your project:  [File permissions for Laravel 5 (and others)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others)

Answer (score 1):

sometimes !! It's just a PHP version related problem. I have just changed the PHP version from 5.6 to 7.0 in PHP configuration of my cPanel.